# Convert a really-large collection to Xml in .NET

Tags: c#, xml, linq, streaming

I have a database result (as a list of items) that is huge. 450K items are returned.

I then use Linq-To-Xml to convert this collection to an `XDocument`. It works - but it's a huge memory hit.

**Is it possible to convert the collection items to XML but not all in memory, at once .. but streaming to a file as the conversation happens?**

The XML data *finally* saves to disk at over 1Gig. So it's fair to assume that the memory consumption will *at least* be this.

So - is there a way to stream the XML segments to disk, as we iterate over each item in the list *instead* of converting the entire result-set to an InMemory `XDocument` and then saving this to disk?

NOTE: Please do not make suggestions about breaking up the list into smaller parts, etc. I understand that, but I've ruled that out.

Here's some sample code I'm doing (to help give you an idea).

```
// Create the xml doc.
var elements = from user in userResults
               select new XElement("user",
                    new XElement("id", user.Id),
               .....<snip>...... );

return new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"), 
           new XElement("users", elements));

// Save the doc to the filesystem.
using (var writer = _fileSystemWrapper.CreateText(destinationXmlFileName))
{
    xmldDocument.Save(writer);
}
```

#### Update

Maybe there's some other tricks like using Linq-To-Xml to create element segments in batches of 10 .. and for each 10, append that to the end of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [XStreamingElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xstreamingelement(v=vs.110).aspx). It would require some small refactoring though, mainly not creating `XDocument` and using different `Save` method.

Here is the corresponding sample to yours just to give you an idea:

```
var elements = from user in userResults
               select new XElement("user",
                    new XElement("id", user.Id),
               .....<snip>...... );

var content = new XStreamingElement("users", elements);

using (var output = _fileSystemWrapper.CreateText(destinationXmlFileName))
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true })
{
    // Use the next line if you don't require standalone="yes" attribute
    // content.Save(writer);
    writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
    content.WriteTo(writer);
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```

Comment: So the `var elements = <linq statement>` is only that - a _statement_. There **is no** `.ToList() / .ToArray()`, etc... which means the data is not actually generated. So .. no massive memory hit. Next, the `new XStreaingElement` also just sets stuff up - still no massive memory hit and serialization. Finally, in the `content.WriteTo(writer)` .. this is where the actually iteration and serialization kicks off ... and it's got the smarts of using the `XStreamingElement` .. so it streams the elements to the stream as it iterates _then_ ..  <-- that about it?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Exactly.